# Managing several classes in php

Tags: php, class, oop

Trying to get my head around classes and OOP

I have the following situation and i define my classes as such

```
// Include database connection class
require_once INCLUDE_PATH.'database.class.php';
$database = new Database;

// include the functions helper class
require_once INCLUDE_PATH.'functions.php';
$functions = new functions();

// include the error handling class
require_once INCLUDE_PATH.'error_handling.php';
$errorHandling = new errorHandling();
```

database.php

```
class Database{

    public function __construct(){

    // Create dsn connection string
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

    $options = array(
        // avoids duplicate connections being opened
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    =>  true,
    // sets error mode if a database error is thrown
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );  

    // Create a new PDO instanace
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch(PDOException $e){ // Catch any errors
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();

        // email the administrator and redirect and display a user friendly message for the user
        $errorHandling->database_connection();
        }

    } // end of construct function to setup database connection
} // end of database class
```

functions.php

```
class functions{

    public function email_admin {

    // run code to email the administrator with the error
    }
}
```

error_handling.php

```
class errorHandling{

public function database_connection(){

    // this handles the code that holds the errors for
    // both the admin message and user message and redirects
    // the user to a page to show the user friendly error
    // if the database connection fails
    // it also runs the code to email the admin before redirecting

    $functions->email_admin();

}
```

So you can see what im trying to do and most likely quite badly. I have extensive error handling for user and admin so im using a class for that so i don't clutter up the code. Im using a helper function and im using the database class which has all the sql stuff.

There are several situations where a database function is using functions in both error handling and functions for emailing the admin. I could just lump everything into 1 big class and solve my issue but that wouldn't be efficient.

I can use global $functions and global $errorHandling within each individual function when i need it but that seems repetitive. Is there a better way to handle this or can you point me to an article or reading that deals with this. Ive tried googling but a lot of the tutorials are very general and im finding it difficult to find something that deals with my specific issue. I also know about extend but it doesn't feel like an appropriate situation for extending the database class and i can still only extend one class i believe.

The problem comes when i try and use:

$errorHandling->database_connection();

within the database class. If i do that i get an error:
Call to a member function database_connection() on a non-object or something similar

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/classobj.examples.php <-- Read this. I would love to be more specific but you are way off in left field. I think reading through these simple examples will help alot. I don't mean this rudely, but whatever you read led you down a destructive path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current problem is a [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem: `$errorHandling` is not defined in the scope of the method in the `Database` class, so you are trying to call the `database_connection()` method on an undefined *thing* (for lack of a better word...).

If your `Database` class depends on several other classes and inheritance is not the obvious way to as there is no real inheritance relationship, you might want to look into **Dependency Injection**. In short, when you construct a `Database` object, you inject the necesary dependancies in the object and assign them to properties of that object so that you have them available there.

A simple example:

Main code:

```
$errorHandling = new errorHandling();
$database = new Database($errorHandling);
```

In the `Database` class:

```
class Database{

    private $_errorHandler;

    public function __construct(errorHandling $errorHandling){

        $this->_errorHandler = $errorHandling;

        // the rest of your code

            // ...
            $this->_errorHandler->database_connection();
```

By the way, you should also check out [Autoloading of classes](http://php.net/autoload), that will make your life a lot easier as the number of classes grows.